# How to make a script run on startup?

Tags: micropython, rp2040

On an Elecfreaks Pico:ed I'm able to write and test MicroPython scripts using Thonny, but how to make it run on startup (when pressing the RESET button)?

How can I do that for other Raspberry Pi Pico based boards? Does it have to be given a specific file name?

Comment: As I understand it, if you name the file "main.py", it will be run at boot.

Comment: I too assumed it may be something like that, but main.py ddn't work..

Comment: The Pico:ed (essentially a Raspbery Pi) has 2 buttons for starting. One is BOOTSELECT and the other is RESET. Tried boith.  Isn't ta Thonny rocessed microPython ptogram compiled to pdseudo-code to be interpreted at run time? OR ystems like Raspberry Pi start executing from  .py source code?

Comment: Did some researtch and apparently the Raspberry Pi like systems can execute microPython directly - that is Thonny doesn't create a pseudo code file to be interpreted. COuld it be that an autiexec.ini like file is neded on th micro-controller and it names the microPython file to run on boot?

Comment: Just to be clear, this is a Raspberry Pi Pico based microcontroller board, not a Raspberry Pi (yes this is confusing). Are you actually using MicroPython on it, or CircuitPython which is what their [documentation](http://wiki.elecfreaks.com/en/pico/picoed/programming-environment-preparation) describes?

Comment: "*How can I do that for other Raspberry Pi Pico based boards?*" Read its manual (not every board works the same just because it contains an RP2040).

Comment: Thank you.

I am using the Pico:ed with Thonny configured with the circuitPython.as cpmpoler/intrpreter. Is that a somewhat different language/libraries than microPython?

I ordered a Raspberry Pi RP2040-Zero Microcontroller PICO RP2040 Dual Develop Board and assume it too can be programmed by a suitably confugured Thonny IDE. How can rthat microcontroller boot resident programs ater they ar tested with Thonny? Is it sufficient to name the program main.py?

Comment: Got it to work. Pico:ed boots with file code.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ESP-32 and ESP-8266 as in some others you'll see that you can find two files after installing MicroPython:

- boot.py
- main.py

Inside boot you can type "import somepackage" and make it run in the boot in the order that you call it, or even run some code.

On Raspberry Pico MicroPython version, this boot.py doesn't exist when fresh installed, nor main.py.

Both should work just fine as you can find them in the port code:

ESP32: https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/ports/esp32/main.c#L140

RP2: https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/ports/rp2/main.c#L180

But be aware that other custom images can change that!
For example, on Pimoroni port, the boot.py doesn't work because it is already utilized by them in another way, but main.py does.

Some other references:

- Boot process in a PyBoard: https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/pyboard/general.html#boot-modes